# Does legislation around government transparency (e.g. FOIA or Sunshine ordinances) apply to public sector hiring processes?

Tags: california, foia

- Can Civil Service applicants be required to sign confidentiality agreements regarding the application and interview process?
- Can FOIA/Sunshine requests enjoin government offices to disclose present and future exam or interview questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can FOIA/Sunshine requests enjoin government offices to disclose
>   present and future exam or interview questions?

[Section 6254(g)](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=GOV&sectionNum=6254.) in the Chapter *Inspection of Public Records* states that

> *this chapter does not require the disclosure of [...] Test questions, scoring keys, and other examination data used to administer a
>   licensing examination, **examination for employment**, or academic
>   examination, except as provided for in Chapter 3 (commencing with
>   Section 99150) of Part 65 of Division 14 of Title 3 of the Education
>   Code.*

(emphasis added)

Thus, it is up to the state agency's discretion whether or not to disclose present and future exam or interview questions.

> Can Civil Service applicants be required to sign confidentiality
>   agreements regarding the application and interview process?

It seems to me that it is permissible, especially if that confidentiality is *reasonably* sought to enforce the protection enacted in § 6254(g). Otherwise, an agency's efforts to preserve the secrecy of examination questions would be futile if an applicant discloses --say, for the benefit of future applicants-- *what* is being tested.